# Как убрать ошибку MemoryError (python3.6.1)

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Вот код программы в которой возникает ошибка при зачитывает более 300 фалов. Эта программа записует папки, [файлы,то что написано в файле], кол-во файлов(числом) в файл.json

```
import json,os,sys
try:
    e=sys.argv[1]
    hjson=sys.argv[2]
    name_ins=sys.argv[3]
except IndexError:
    e = input("Введите путь к папке которую нужно занести в инсталлер")
    hjson = input("Введите путь к папке в которую нужно будет установить установщик")
    name_ins = input("Введите названия JSON файла(без формата)")
dirs=[]
files=[]
number_of_file=0
dirs.append(os.path.split(os.path.abspath(e))[1])
def scandir1(m):
    global number_of_file
    for i in os.scandir(m):
        if i.is_dir():
            print(os.path.abspath(i),"-->",hjson+"\\"+name_ins+".json")
            dirs.append(os.path.relpath(i,e))
            scandir1(os.path.abspath(i))
        else:
            number_of_file+=1
            print(os.path.abspath(i),"-->",hjson+"\\"+name_ins+".json")
            files.append([os.path.relpath(i, e),
                              open(os.path.abspath(i), "rb").read().decode("Latin-1")])
scandir1(e)
print("Создание файла...")
y=open(hjson+"\\"+name_ins+".json","w")
print("Загрузка данных...")
json.dump([dirs,files,number_of_file], y, sort_keys=True, indent=4, skipkeys=True)
print("===============")
y.close()
```

А это сам инсталлер:

```
import json as js
import os, codecs, sys
er=0
try:
    locate_wer=sys.argv[1]
    locate_dir=sys.argv[2]
except IndexError:
    locate_wer=input("Введите путь к JSON файлу")
    locate_dir = input("Введите путь к папке куда установить")
y=open(locate_wer,"r")
r=js.load(y)
y.close()
files=r[1]
dirs=r[0]#сами библиотеки
gh=dirs[0]#название бибиотеки откуда мы скачуем
try:
    os.mkdir(locate_dir+"\\"+gh)
except FileExistsError: pass
for y in dirs[1:]:
    print(locate_dir+"\\"+gh+"\\"+y)
    os.mkdir(locate_dir+"\\"+gh+"\\"+y)
for y1 in files:
    er+=1
    try:
        t=open(locate_dir+"\\"+gh+"\\"+y1[0],"w")
        print(locate_dir + "\\" + gh + "\\" + y1[0])
        t.write(y1[1])
        t.close()
    except UnicodeEncodeError:
        t = codecs.open(locate_dir + "\\" + gh + "\\" + y1[0], "wb")
        print(locate_dir + "\\" + gh + "\\" + y1[0])
        t.write(y1[1].encode("Latin-1"))
        t.close()
```

Через функцию(или метод, не знаю как правильно назвать)

`json.dump([dirs,files,number_of_file], y, sort_keys=True, indent=4,skipkeys=True)`

Мы вписываем в файл список в котором первое папки второе файлы а третье кол-во файлов. И если мы берем много папок и файлов то вылазит ошибка MemoryError. Я думаю эту проблемму можно решить таким образом -- если скрипт обнаружил папку или файл сразу записывать этот файл или папку в файл.json и так далее. Только я не знаю как дописывать.

Так вот если поможете,(а это врятли будет кто либо делать)зарание вам спасибо.

Comment: Если нормально объясните проблему, то возможно кто-то поможет. Сейчас толком ничего не понятно.

Comment: Какая фактическая задача? Я предполагаю, что вы пытаетесь содержимое всех файлов загрузить в список, в итоге память просто переполняется (нужно учитывать, что в памяти данные из файлов могут занимать больше места, чем в файлах). Возможно вам просто нужно обрабатывать файлы частями (или хотя бы по одному), результат выгружать на диск, переходить к следующему файлу. Можно вообще текстовые файлы построчно обрабатывать, тогда потребление памяти программой будет минимальным.

Comment: @insolor да вы правы. Я немного изменил вопрос.

Comment: В json (средствами модуля json) нельзя дописывать, только заново дампить с заменой содержимого файла. Если у вас там просто список файлов, и файлов всего лишь около 200, то не должно быть переполнения памяти. Скорее всего у вас где-то ошибка в коде, не видя код нельзя сказать в чем проблема.

Comment: @insolor  кардинально изменил вопросс

Comment: Я так понимаю, вы все-таки в json пробуете дописывать еще и содержимое файлов? Это не очень удачное решение, потому что приходится загружать все файлы в память, а потом дампить в файл, в процессе загрузки файл, если файлы большие. Если нужно все файлы упаковать в один, можно просто их все скреплять в один (как бинарный файл), а в конце добавить таблицу смещений файлов от начала и их имен/путей, а потом при установке считывать таблицу в конце файла, и "распаковывать" их. Вообще, логичнее было бы использовать архив (zip например).

Comment: @insolor Понятно. А как называется модуль python для сжатия(архивации) файлов?

Comment: Для работы с zip архивами - zipfile

Comment: @insolor А есть модуль для работы допустим с *.tar

Comment: Есть, внезапно называется tarfile

Comment: @insolor у меня получилось записывать много файлов, но потом, как читать этот файл?

Comment: Смотря как записали. Если в архив, то модулем для обработки этого архива. Если просто в один файл, то в конце нужно добавить "заголовок" с указанием имен, путей файлов, и смещений где этот файл в общем файле начинается, и еще в конце добавить размер "заголовка", чтобы понимать откуда он начинается. Все в бинарном виде (размер заголовка как 4-байтное беззнаковое целое число например)

Comment: @insolor Извините не так выразился читать то понятно как но вот если файл превышает 13 гб. то скрипт говорит: идика ты лесом со своим файлом. P .S. я сделал вопрос на эту тему     https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/728923/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-13-%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9-json-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D0%B2-python3-6-1