# Как прочитать 13 гигабайтовый .json файл в python3.6.1

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Вы меня наверное спросите где или как я нашел этот файл.

А я вам отвечаю -- вот так:

```
import json,os,sys
e = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\T-Rex help\Mount & Blade - Napoleonic Wars Enhancement"
hjson = "."
name_ins = "filejson"
y=open(hjson+"\\"+name_ins+".json","w")
y.write("[")
dirs=[]
po=0
files=[]
number_of_file=0
y.write("[")
json.dump(os.path.split(os.path.abspath(e))[1],y)
def scandir1(m):
    global number_of_file
    for i in os.scandir(m):
        if i.is_dir():
            number_of_file += 1
            print(os.path.abspath(i),"-->",hjson+"\\"+name_ins+".json")
            y.write(",")
            json.dump(os.path.relpath(i, e),y)
            scandir1(os.path.abspath(i))
        else:
            pass
scandir1(e)
y.write("]")
y.write(",[")
def scandir2(m):
    global number_of_file, po
    for i in os.scandir(m):
        if i.is_dir():
            scandir2(os.path.abspath(i))
        else:
            number_of_file+=1
            if po==0:
                po=1
            else:
                y.write(",")
            print(os.path.abspath(i),"-->",hjson+"\\"+name_ins+".json")
            json.dump([os.path.relpath(i, e),
                              open(os.path.abspath(i), "rb").read().decode("Latin-1")],
                      y)
scandir2(e)
y.write("]")
y.write("]")
print("Загрузка данных...")
print("===============")
y.close()
```

Эта программа записывает (сразу) в файл.json список `[dirs,["name_file","file_read"]]`

Кстати игра C:\Program Files (x86)\T-Rex help\Mount & Blade - Napoleonic Wars Enhancement весит примерно 3 гб.

Все бы нечего, но когда пытаешься это дело прочитать и по циклу установить(то есть сначала папки создаются, а потом файлы).

Вот собственно пример:

```
import json as js
import os, codecs
er=0
locate_wer=input("Введите путь к JSON файлу")
locate_dir = input("Введите путь к папке куда установить")
y=open(locate_wer,"r")
print(y.readline())
y.close()
files=r[1]
dirs=r[0]
gh=dirs[0]#gh это название папки из которой были взяты файлы снизу эта папка  создаётся 
try:
    os.mkdir(locate_dir+"\\"+gh)
except FileExistsError: pass
for y in dirs[1:]:
    print(locate_dir+"\\"+gh+"\\"+y)
    os.mkdir(locate_dir+"\\"+gh+"\\"+y)
for y1 in files:
    er+=1
    try:
        t=open(locate_dir+"\\"+gh+"\\"+y1[0],"w")
        print(locate_dir + "\\" + gh + "\\" + y1[0])
        t.write(y1[1])
        t.close()
    except UnicodeEncodeError:
        t = codecs.open(locate_dir + "\\" + gh + "\\" + y1[0], "wb")
        print(locate_dir + "\\" + gh + "\\" + y1[0])
        t.write(y1[1].encode("Latin-1"))
        t.close()
```

Я вообще думаю, что надо читать по частям, но не знаю как

**Так вот как прочитать этот файл?**

Comment: А что и зачем вы вообще пытаетесь сделать? O_o Использовать для такого json - это как пытаться перетаскать полтонны гвоздей россыпью, используя только пластиковый пакет и жаловаться при этом что пакет быстро рвётся.

Comment: @ знаю знаю, я просто хотел попробовать скорей поэкспериментировать, можно ли сделать инсталятор с помощью json. Этой программой вообще пытаюсь сделать инсталятор.

Comment: **Не нужно** делать 13 Гб json. Вам нужен либо бинарный файл, либо архив, как я уже писал в комментариях к этому вопросу https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/728237/1365

Comment: @Gleb, я ближе к вечеру набросаю пример как несколько файлов упаковать в бинарном формате.

Comment: Кст, а как насчет того, чтобы заполнять не json, а базу данных, например `sqlite`?

Comment: @gil9red Не знаю, я попробую. Но я уже решил, что  с таблицами мучатся не буду.

Comment: @gil9red, поскольку речь идет об инсталляторе, то логично было бы использовать просто архив. Мне если честно вообще не понятно упорное (в нескольких вопросах) желание использовать json.

Comment: @insolor, вариант с архивом лучший вариант :)

Comment: Используйте `mmap(2)`.

Comment: @insolor так можете показать пожалуйста несколько примеров как упаковывать файлы в бинарном формате. И насчет упорного желания -- хотел создать инсталятор, но не знал как и вот решил попробовать с json.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Не очень хорошая идея использовать для таких целей json:

1. JSON текстовый формат (не предназначен для бинарных данных, которыми являются исполняемые файлы, библиотеки, файлы ресурсов - например, изображения).
2. Данные в JSON хранятся в структурированном виде, поэтому для прочтения их приходится читать весь файл, что может привести к переполнению доступной памяти, если файл большой.

С другой стороны - бинарные данные можно собрать в бинарный файл (пусть даже это будет тупая склейка файлов последовательно друг за другом, или еще лучше, если это будет сжатый формат, пусть даже просто ZIP), а в JSON хранить информацию об именах файлов, куда их разархивировать, смещения каждого файла внутри общего бинарного файла (если это просто склейка всех файлов вместе).

При желании сам JSON можно прикрепить к тому же бинарному файлу, например в конец файла. В конец добавлять удобнее чем в начало, т.к. уже будет известна вся информация о файлах (те же смещения от начала общего файла для каждого из файлов), и при добавлении новых файлов, можно будет этот "хвост" отрезать, дописать новый файл, и прикрепить новый "хвост" со всей старой информацией, плюс информацией о новом файле. Если добавлять в начало файла, то сначала в файл нужно записать JSON, заранее просчитав все смещения, потом дописать все файлы, и при добавлении нового файла нужно будет в новый файл записывать JSON заголовок, а потом после него дописывать все данные из старого файла. Кстати, в формате ZIP "оглавление" хранится как раз в конце файла.

Итог - бинарные данные большого объема храним отдельно, метаинформацию - отдельно.

Как собрать несколько файлов в один файл:

```
import shutil


def concat_files(src_files, dest):
    offset = 0
    with open(dest, 'wb') as dest:
        for filename in src_files:
            with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
                shutil.copyfileobj(file, dest)
            new_offset = dest.tell()            
            yield filename, offset, new_offset - offset
            offset = new_offset


files = ['abc.txt', 'def.txt', 'xyz.txt']

offsets = list(concat_files(files, 'file.bin'))

print(offsets)  # [('abc.txt', 0, 1810), ('def.txt', 1810, 129769), ('xyz.txt', 131579, 2197)]
```

Функция принимает на вход список файлов и имя выходного файла, записывает все файлы из списка в один, и возвращает для каждого файла его смещение от начала файла (номер байта, с которого файл начинается) и размер файла. Чтобы прочитать один файл из общего, нужно переместиться на его начало, и считать количество байт равное размеру исходного файла.

Полученный список уже можно сохранять в JSON и использовать любым способом.

Функция [**shutil.copyfileobj**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfileobj) позволяет копировать файлы большого размера, не загружая их в память целиком. Копирование происходит блоками, размер блока можно задать 3-м параметром.

Функция "извлечения" файла:

```
def extract(file_name, dest_name, offset, size, block_size=1024):
    with open(file_name, 'rb') as file:
         file.seek(offset)
         with open(dest_name, 'wb') as dest:
             while size > 0:
                 block = file.read(block_size if size > block_size else size)
                 dest.write(block)
                 size -= block_size

# Пример использования:
extract('file.bin', 'def.txt', 1810, 129769)
```

Нужно учитывать, что файлы будут храниться в несжатом виде, а многие файлы неплохо сжимаются, поэтому можно было бы вместо своего бинарного формата использовать использовать даже просто ZIP, тем более что его поддержка есть в Python из коробки.

Comment: То есть вы хотите сказать что если у нас есть допустим 3 текстовых файла с текстовым содержанием abs у первого у 2 asd у 3 ert то в file.bin это будет выглядеть как-то так absasdert а в .json будет указано возврат функции dest.tell() ну и другие параметры

Comment: Да, файлы склеятся, а в отдельном файле можно указать начала и длины файлов.

Comment: зачем нужно block_size

Comment: @Gleb чтобы при копировании файла не грузить его в память целиком, а копировать небольшими блоками.

Comment: интересный метод

Comment: @Gleb это довольно обычный метод. Как ещё скопировать файл размером больше размера оперативной памяти или просто с минимальным её потреблением?

Answer (score 1):

Вместо того, чтобы считывать json-файл целиком и создавать в памяти его представление, можно анализировать его в процессе считывания. Например, с помощью [iJSON](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ijson).