# Как открыть в питоне файл с весом в несколько в Гигабайт?

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

У меня есть JSON файл весом в 6 гигабайт, как мне его открыть, прочитать и в дальнейшем работать?

Я пробавал сделать это стандартными методами open, но получал ошибку MemoryError

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/728923/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-13-%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9-json-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D0%B2-python3-6-1

Comment: Еще рекомендуют попробовать SQLite, если получиться напишите.

Comment: Читать json потоковым ридером. Прочитали токен - обработали, прочитали следующий - обработали. По ссылке выше есть библиотека ijson - вот с помощью чего-то такого нужно читать. Непонятно, почему там принято и заплюсовано сообщение insolor'а, которое не даёт ответа на вопрос.